# Laravel 5 select only relationship data on hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an application that has `projects` and projects have `plot_types`.

I want to be able to check if a plot_type exists under the current project.

I have the following code:

```
$testResult = $project->with(['plotTypes' => function($query) use ($row) {
            $query->where('name', $row->plot_name);
        }])->first()
```

This produces the following MySQL:

```
select exists(select * from `projects` where exists (select * from `projects_plot_types` where `projects_plot_types`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` and `name` = ?)) as `exists`
```

This SQL returns rows that are NOT related to the `$project` object.  For example when I do `dd($project)` I get:

```
#attributes: array:11 [▼
    "id" => "4"
    "name" => "xxx"
    "number" => "1234"
    "builder" => "1"
    "overall_budget" => "3456.00"
    "start_date" => "2016-03-31"
    "end_date" => "2016-04-30"
    "created_date" => "2016-03-16 15:22:05"
    "updated_date" => "2016-03-16 15:22:07"
  ]
```

Yet, when I do `dd($testResult);` it gives;

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
"plotTypes" => Collection {#767 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => ProjectsPlotTypes {#770 ▼
      #table: "projects_plot_types"
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => "1"
        "project_id" => "1"
        "name" => "TYPE 1  - VENTILATION"
        "budget" => "324.67"
      ]
```

Notice, the project_id above shows `1`.  This is not related to the current project as the current project id is `4`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those potentially confusing parts of the ActiveRecord model. All your model instances contain the same methods used to retrieve model instances, so it easy think something should work one way when it really doesn't.

Calling `$project->with()`, this is the exact same as calling `Project::with()`. Even though you're calling `with()` on an instance of the project, it isn't going to restrict the loaded objects to only those related to your instance.

When you call `$project->with()`, the first thing it does is create a new query for all projects, and then adds in the eager loading. You then call `first()`, which just gets the first project record, and all its eager loaded objects.

To get the plot types for your specific project, you have a couple options.

1. Just query the relationship. `$project->plotTypes()` gives you a base query for all the plot types associated with your project. You can add your constraints and get the records from there.

   ```
   $plotTypes = $project->plotTypes()->where('name', $row->plot_name)->get();
   dd($plotTypes);
   ```
2. Load the related plot types with constraints:

   ```
   // assume your project doesn't have any plottypes loaded yet
   $project = Project::find(1);

   // load the plottypes relation with constraints
   $project->load(['plotTypes' => function($query) use ($row) {
       $query->where('name', $row->plot_name);
   }]);
   dd($project->plotTypes);
   ```
3. Filter the already loaded `Collection` of related plot types. `$project->plotTypes` has all the plot types related to your project, but you can use the `where()` method on the `Collection` (different than the `where()` on the query) to filter through the records in the `Collection`.

   ```
   // assume your project already has all plotTypes loaded
   $project = Project::with('plotTypes')->find(1);

   // you just want to get a subset of those pre-loaded plottypes
   $plotTypes = $project->plotTypes->where('name', $row->plot_name);
   dd($plotTypes);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the whereHas method to do the filtering instead of the with

```
$testResult = $project->whereHas('plotTypes' => function($query) use ($row) {
        $query->where('name', $row->plot_name);
 })->with('plotTypes')->first();
```

And moreover do you want to **get** all the related records or only the **first** record?

if **all** then change the **first()** to **get()**

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this but it still doesn't give the expected result.  If I do `first()` it gives me the relationship with 2 plotTypes but both not attached to the current project.

Comment: first change the inner $query to $query->where('name', '=',$row->plot_name); and let see what happens. second Log::info($row->plot_name) and see if it contains something